# How to narrow callable vs newable type?

Tags: typescript

I probably have a problem or misunderstanding for the narrowing, especially the Fnc (callable) vs. of type Class (newable).

The code below works in Playgruond, but it has poor autocompletion as you can see in the first image.

The question is pls how to achieve accurate autocompletion for `Login action` for example ?

Is this really a Fnc vs Class narrowing problem or the problem is somewhere else ?

Pls help me, sincerely thanks in advance.

```js
type Fnc =  (...args: any[]) => any
type Class = { new(...args: readonly unknown[]): unknown }
type Interface<C extends Class> = InstanceType<C>

declare function Test<F extends Fnc> (type: "Precondition", f:F, params:Parameters<F>[0]): typeof Test
declare function Test<C extends Class> (type: "Actor" | "System", c:C, members:Partial<Interface<C>>): typeof Test

declare const Browser: (params: {"Address": "https://sys.tem" | "http://test-env.sys.tem"}) => void
declare class Login {
  "User": string
  "Password": string
  "action": "Sign in" | "Register" | "Request password"
  "Message": "Invalid credentials" | "Credentials are required"
}

Test 
("Precondition", Browser, {"Address": "https://sys.tem"})
("Actor",        Login,   {"User": "KO", "Password": "invalid", "action": "Sign in"})
//                                                               ^_ POOR AUTOCOMPLETION HERE ? 
("System",       Login,   {"Message": "Invalid credentials"}
```

[link to Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NDAxRm)

poor autocomplete:

[image]

**INVESTIGATION:**

If I change the implementation this way ...

[link to Playground 2](https://tsplay.dev/w8Vjdm)

... then the autocomplete is perfect - but I do not understand why ?

[image]

Comment: Not the DV, but there are a few errors in that playground, so why are you surprised autocomplete doesn't work? Also curious why you're using an intersection of function types instead of an overload for Test? And why it and Browser are uppercase which violates common JS/TS practice? And why you defined Class and Interface that way? There's a lot that's unclear here.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you, I am surprised because there is no autocomplete resp. it is to wide (see, I edited the question).  This is "a kind of Specification", where for example uppercased Browser or Login are names of appropriate Web pages, so it is so only for clarity to testers :)

Comment: If you fix your code and playground I'll vote to reopen, but autocompletion relies on type information, and the errors in the playground are telling you the compiler *can't figure out the type of your expression*, so of course autocomplete that depends on that type isn't going to work.

Comment: @JaredSmith I fixed code in playground and concised/precised my question - is it OK for you now? Regards.

Comment: I mean, yeah, it's fixed and it's better, but AFAICT autocompletion seems to work correctly now, so... problem solved?

Comment: @JaredSmith I am attaching a picture with the problem - I think it is there. Or do you have a different situation?

Comment: Oh wait, you're right. It was only doing text autocompletion, not getting it from the type. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @JaredSmith I apologize for not being clear the first time and thank you for your patience :) Best regards

Comment: It does work. Just don't use quotes.

Comment: @kelsny thanks, without quotes it is better. But I am afraid that I need them because `User` can also be `User name` .  Any other suggestions please ?

Comment: It should still suggest that without quotes.

Comment: @kelsny if I changed the implementation this way https://tsplay.dev/w8Vjdm - than the autocomplete is now perfect, but I do not understand why (pls see additional image in the question) ?

Answer (score 0):

If I rewrite the code this way - the autocompletion is now perfect everywhere - but I still do not understand what is the real difference opposite to the question code ...

```js
type Fnc =  (...args: any[]) => any
type Class = { new(...args: readonly unknown[]): unknown }
type Interface<C extends Class> = InstanceType<C>

declare function Test<F extends Fnc, C extends Class> (...args: 
  ["Precondition", F, Parameters<F>[0]] | 
  ["Actor" | "System", C, members:Partial<Interface<C>>]): 
typeof Test 

declare const Browser: (params: {"Address": "https://sys.tem" | "http://test-env.sys.tem"}) => void
declare class Login {
  "User": string
  "Password": string
  "action": "Sign in" | "Register" | "Request password"
  "Message": "Invalid credentials" | "Credentials are required"
}

Test 
("Precondition", Browser, {"Address": "https://sys.tem"})
("Actor",        Login,   {"User": "KO", "Password": "invalid", "action": "Sign in"})
//                                                               ^_ PERFECT AUTOCOMPLETION HERE ! 
("System",       Login,   {"Message": "Invalid credentials"})
```

link to Playground 3 - https://tsplay.dev/mb3g9W